# Will my Rails app work on Openshift (free)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, openshift

I developed a Rails app on my Macbook and I'm now looking to host it on Openshift's (free) option. But, I'm wondering if it will work?

My app has the following specs:

Rails 4.2.5, Ruby 2.2.3, Postgres 9.4.5. It creates user directories and writes text files which are publicly accessible.
i.e  www.my_app.com\user_dir\file1.txt  etc..

It appears Openshift only has earlier versions of Ruby, Rails, Postgres available. But can I safely downgrade Ruby, Rails and Postgress to make it work? Do I really need to? If so, how?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: *Can* you? Sure, but you'd need to update your code appropriately. Do you really need to? ... Well yeah, if they don't offer a version you're trying to use it's not going to work. The file uploading depends on OpenShift's functionality which I don't know anything about.

Comment: Do I need to worry about Rails and Postgres? Their versions seem so close. And with Ruby... Should I just run RMV to downgrade on my local machine and test the app? Can I easily set it back if it doesn't work?

Comment: "So close" may or may not work; it's impossible to guess. It depends on your app. If you're using a Ruby version manager then setting it back is precisely the same operation as setting it to something else.

Comment: So can I use RVM to set it from 2.2.3 to 2.0.0, and if that doesn't work, set it back to 2.2.3? (without problems)

Comment: I assume you mean `rvm`? I mean, that's the point of rvm, right? To set versions of languages and gemsets?

Comment: `rvm list` only shows the Rubies you have installed, not that are available. `rvm list known` lists the Rubies you *may* install.

Comment: ok so that means I have both 2.0.0 and 2.2.3 installed but my app is set to use 2.2.3?

Comment: You state your app is set to use 2.2.3, but I have no way of knowing how that expectation is handled, e.g., are you using an rvm default, are you using a `.ruby-version` file in the app, etc. (This question is rhetorical; I'm not asking.) `rvm list` shows the Rubies you currently have installed. `rvm info` in your project directory will list out everything rvm knows about Ruby things related to your project and its directory. You might want to take a small step back and check out more rvm docs before going too much further.

Comment: You make good points, but I'm hoping someone with more Openshift experience will step in and tell me what i should do. Since they are not making the latest versions available, they must have this problem all the time.

Comment: ... You should test it.

Comment: Im about to type rvm use 2.0.0 in the terminal and see what happens. Hopefully I can type rvm use 2.2.3 and everything will be back, if it fails. I'd like to take advantage of the free Openshift hosting, so I don't have much choice  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this page (https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions/4.2.5), a Ruby version of 1.9.3 or higher is required for rails 4.2.5.  If you git push to OpenShift Online it will install rails 4.2.5 and it's dependent gems without issue (I have just tested this).

As for Ruby 2.2, you would need to downgrade to Ruby 2.0 and test your site using rvm.  It should be trivial to do this using RVM, and if it doesn't work you can just rvm use 2.2 and everything should be fine again.

Whether this works or not really hinges on what features of Ruby 2.2.3 and PostgreSQL 9.4.5 that you are using that are NOT available in earlier versions.  It's quite possible that you are not using any of the newest features and everything would work just fine, but you are really the only one that knows that for sure.

It should be pretty easy to fire up a small gear on OpenShift and do a "git push" and see if it works or not.  If it doesn't, you should begin to see some errors in the log files or on the deploy log that would tell you what you would need to change/fix for it to work correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. I will soon (after I run a few errands) do a rvm use 2.0.0, and test the app locally. It's really not too complex of an app, and I doubt any of the gems needed anything above 2.0.0... I'll leave this open for a few hours then vote answers this afternoon, to see what others say. Thanks

Comment: Do I also need to change my gemfile to say ruby '2.0.0' instead of ruby '2.2.3' after I run rvm use 2.0.0?

Comment: I don't have ruby version information in my default OpenShift Gemfile, so I would say to remove it, and put your ruby version & gemset information into your .ruby-version and .ruby-gemset files for rvm/rbenv to use

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested in hearing from the person who voted down my original question...

Do you not think many people face the same issues -- when it is natural to use/download the latest versions of ruby/rails etc while developing on a local machine?

So, why the vote down?